# How to get a sans-serif math wide hat in {xe|lua}latex?

Tags: math-mode, xetex, luatex, sans-serif

Feeding

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\(\widehat{\strut~~~\,\,\,\ \ \ \mskip10mu\mkern10mu\strut}\)

\(\mathsf{\widehat{\strut~~~\,\,\,\ \ \ \mskip10mu\mkern10mu\strut}}\)
\end{document}
```

to `xelatex` produces

[image: xelatex output]

and feeding it to `lualatex` results in

[image: lualatex output]

As you notice, the sans-serif hat is narrow in both cases whatever junk you put inside.  How to produce a wide hat (without anything under it) in the scope of `\mathsf{...}`? 
Here, we don't really want an accent, but only a decently wide hat (say, 1em) as a symbol in a sans-serif math font.

Crosspost: http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=32819&p=110398

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go back to `\mathnormal` first:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\(\widehat{\strut~~~\,\,\,\ \ \ \mskip10mu\mkern10mu\strut}\)

\(\mathsf{\widehat{\strut~~~\,\,\,\ \ \ \mskip10mu\mkern10mu\strut}}\)


\(\mathsf{\mathnormal{\widehat{\strut~~~\,\,\,\ \ \ \mskip10mu\mkern10mu\strut}}}\)
\end{document}
```